# how to run elasticsearch file from ./bin/elasticsearch in windows

Tags: elasticsearch

i am facing this error when i try to the elasticsearch from bin foldeR. I have download elasticsearch from this link https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.6.2-darwin-x86_64.tar.gz. 
[image]

Comment: can you show the content of your bin folder, and it seems you are trying to run on window  platform where .bat is the executable , so you need to run .bat file

Comment: From your bin folder run command : elasticsearch.bat

Comment: run `bin\elasticsearch.bat` (windows = backslashes, *nix = forward slashes)

Comment: @jehanzaib were u able to resolve the issue

Comment: Do you how to connect apache with elastic search?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62318385/how-to-spark-classpath-when-launching-your-notebook

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja kindly check the above linkl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment it seems you are trying to run on window  platform where .bat is executable, you should run `elasticsearch.bat` file from the `bin` folder.